# Misusing of <Link> tag in react-router-dom (the last version)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

when I add Link tag in the component Login the page content disappears, what might be the problem?

Login.js (without Link tag):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function Login() {
  return (
    <div className='container  mx-auto'>
      <form className='col-md-5  mx-auto'>
        <h2 className='m-5'>Login into MERN Project</h2>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required/>
          <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" required/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <nav>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrUTz.jpg)

Login.js with Link tag:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'  

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className='container  mx-auto'>        
      <form className='col-md-5  mx-auto'>
        <h2 className='m-5'>Login into MERN Project</h2>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required/>
          <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" required/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <nav>
        <Link className=''>Not a member? Register here</Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

The output is empty page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea2cm.jpg)

Comment: can you please share the dev console usually by clicking `f12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Link Component add link destination..

```
<Link to="/register" > Not a member? Register here</Link>
```